# How can i delete largest contour in a skeleton image in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour, scikit-image

I would like to delete the circumference (the outermost perimeter of a sign) of this wheel skeleton sign except what's inside.
I think about a function findcontours() and delete the largest contour that i found

This is the input image:

[image: Original image]

Skeletonized:

[image: skeleton image]

but unfortunately this is my output image:

[image: skeleton image without largest contour]

Why it does not remain only with 2 crossed segments and a segment is made by a lot of dots

```
from __future__ import division
import mahotas as mh
import pymorph as pm
import numpy as np

import os
import math

import cv2
from skimage import io
import scipy
from skimage import morphology

complete_path = 'DUPLInuova/ruote 7/e (11).jpg'

fork = mh.imread(complete_path)  
fork = fork[:,:,0]# extract one component, ex R 

#structuring elements
disk7 = pm.sedisk(3)#size 7x7: 7=3+1+3
disk5 = pm.sedisk(2)

#Just a simple thresholding with white background
bfork = fork < 150
bfork = mh.morph.dilate(bfork, disk7)

gray = cv2.imread(complete_path,0)
originale = gray
print("gray")
print(gray.shape)
cv2.imshow('graybin',gray)
cv2.waitKey()

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) 
imgbnbin = thresh
print("shape imgbnbin")
print(imgbnbin.shape)
cv2.imshow('binaria',imgbnbin)
cv2.waitKey()
shape = list(gray.shape)
w = int( (shape[0]/100 )*5)
h = int((shape[1]/100)*5)
print(w)
print(h)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(w,h)) #con 4,4 si vede tutta la stella e riconosce piccoli oggetti
from skimage.morphology import square

graydilate = np.array(imgbnbin, dtype=np.float64)
graydilate = morphology.binary_dilation(graydilate, square(w))
graydilate = morphology.binary_dilation(graydilate, square(w))

out = morphology.skeletonize(graydilate>0)
img = out.astype(float)
cv2.imshow('scikitimage',img)
cv2.waitKey()
img = img.astype(np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('scikitconvert',img)
cv2.waitKey()

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print(len(contours))

# calculating area for deleting little signs
Areacontours = list()
calcarea = 0.0
unicocnt = 0.0
for i in range (0, len(contours)):
    area = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    #print("area")
    print(area)
    if (area > 90 ): 
        if (calcarea<area):
            calcarea = area
            unicocnt = contours[i]

cnt = unicocnt
ara = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
print("cnt")
print(ara)

#delete largest contour
cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,255,0),1)
cv2.imshow('img del contour',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

**UPDATE SOLUTION** (and new question):

if i make a deep copy of the skeletonized img after this line of code: 
    img = img.astype(np.uint8) #after skeletonization procedure

I can use find_contour with copied image and apply a draw_contour to original image and that's all!

My questions are:

Why find contour edit my image and i'm forced to use a temporary image?
Why matplotlib show me the right result and cv2 imshow don't (it show me a black image)?

New part of code:

```
import copy
imgcontour = copy.copy(img)

imgcnt = img
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgcontour,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE )
print(len(contours))

cnt = contours[0]

cv2.drawContours(img,[cnt],0,(0,0,0),1)

cv2.imshow('imgcv2black',img)
cv2.waitKey()

plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

[image: correct result in matplotlib]

**UPDATE FLOODFILE+DILATE:**

It is correct the floodfill-dilate procedure?
Where its' wrong?

```
a = np.ones((212,205), dtype=np.uint8)
#myMask = zeros(a.shape[0:2], dtype = uint8)

maskr = np.zeros(a.shape,np.uint8)
print(maskr.shape)
print(img[0])

cv2.floodFill(img,mask =maskr, seedPoint = (0,0), newVal = 1)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3)) 
img = cv2.dilate(img, element)

cv2.imshow('flood',img)
cv2.waitKey()
plt.gray()
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

and i unfortunately obtain this:

[image: floodfil+dilate]

Answer (score 1):

Another way you might achieve your desired result is to do a flood fill on the skeletonized image.  Since the outer boundary is closed it will select all the pixels outside of the object.  A simple dilation can then be applied to expand the filled region to include the outer ring.  Apply this as a mask and remove any pixels that have been flood filled + dilation.  This will leave only the center of the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be to label the components of contours in the image. In such a case you can extract the contours that directly interest you. And since the labelling starts outside topologically, if one displays all contour labels other than the first one you should have your result. In a case where the contours are already closed a skeleton would not be necessary! Also one can use thinning further to obtain thin contours if the ones we start of with are thick.

Input: I

[image]

Labelled contours:  L = bwlabel(~I);

[image]

Removing the largest outer contour: figure, imshow(L>1)

[image]

This must be possible to replicate in [scikits](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.label) connected component labeling setup.

You can also calculate the size of these components and get their lengths (sum(sum(L==1)) and so on)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the circular Hough transform to try and locate the wheel rim, and then work from there.